# Sony Vaio: Battery Level stuck at 80%

Tags: windows-7, battery, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio VPCF120FD laptop. The battery level seems maximum when it's plugged but when I click on the battery icon, it says the battery level is 80%, plugged in, and not charging. How can I fix this as it can be charged up to 100%?

Answer (score 4):

It's about Vaio's Battery Care function. Battery Care function lets you to hold your laptop's battery level at 80% or 50% to maximize battery life. It seems yours was set to 80%.

To disable Battery Care function, click on Start Orb and type "Vaio Control Center". When Control Center is opened, select Power Management > Battery from the left pane. Now remove the check mark in the box next to "Enable Battery Care Function" by clicking on it. Click OK and that's all. Now your laptop will charge your battery until it's 100% full.